# SELECT Query in JPA & Optimistic Locking

Tags: postgresql, jpa, optimistic-locking

I am having a problem with a certain SELECT query when I have something else locked. For instance:

I set a `OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT` lock on one object in `Table 1` and in the meantime there was another transaction that contained a SELECT query on `Table 2`. `Table 2`, however, doesn't have any database objects (foreign keys or other type of constraints) that connect it to `Table 1`. But when the second SELECT query occurs, the `OptimisticLockException` is thrown.

Does anybody have an idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely OptimisticLockException (OLE) is thrown only by select queries. I'm assuming you did make an update somewhere.

WHen using optimistic locking typically entities have version column (marked by `@Version` annotation). OLE commonly occur when the entity to be synchronized to the database is stale. For example (each step below is 1 single db transaction):

1. Bob obtain a 'user' entity from database. As per now this user's version is 1. This user entity then get passed to a view form / user interface for editing.
2. Before Bob finish editing, Sue also obtains the same user from database, made her change and save her edits, hence incrementing version label to 2
3. When Bob tried to save his changes, JPA notices the version of the user entity is no longer 1, his version of the user is stale, then OLE is thrown

Typically best thing to do is capture the OLE, and present a message to the user saying  something along the line: "Hey someone edited the same entity and saved first. Do you want to overwrite / merge / throw away your change?"

Comment: Yeah as I wrote before, it's happening on Select so no update,delete or change has been done, and it's happening on totally different entity than the locked one.

Comment: Does your entity has a `@Version` column?

Comment: The one that I am locking yes.

Comment: But why Optimictic Locking happens in the SELECT query? I think it should be thrown in the transaction which makes updates